# MySQL create new table from existing one

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table `Table_A` that lists ranges of numbers with their corresponding value:

```
beg_number
end_number
value
```

and need a script that creates a new table `Table_B` with two fields that is an exhaustive list of all numbers with their corresponding value:

number
value

```
beg    end    value

 1      6       11
 7      9       13
 11     14      6
 15     19      3
```

to

```
number value
 1      11
 2      11
 3      11
 4      11
 5      11
 6      11
 7      13
 8      13
 9      13
 11     6
 12     6
 13     6
 14     6
 15     3
 16     3
 17     3
 18     3
```

Can this be done through a MySQL script only?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I am asking if there is any way to make this with MySQL script only.

Comment: There is. It will most likely have to involve a cursor unless you have a table that provides a full range of numbers.

Comment: I have gaps between the ranges.

Comment: Then you'll have to try a cursor.

Comment: What are you calling a "MySQL script only"? Just a query, or does that include stored procedures?

Comment: Both. Query and/or stored procedures.

Comment: Is there a maximum gap between the `beg_number` and `end_number`?

Comment: @PeteGO no max nor min gap

Comment: I know you've mentioned it is MySql, but could you do this in Sql Server?  I could offer up a nice solution using a CTE in that case.  If not I'll think some more.

Comment: No can't use SQL Server,i am going to try Cursor, Thanks Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Store procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat()
BEGIN
  DECLARE xbeg INT;
  DECLARE xend INT;
  DECLARE xvalue INT;
  DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT beg, end, value FROM TableA;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN cur1;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH FROM cur1 INTO xbeg, xend, xvalue;
    IF done THEN LEAVE read_loop; END IF;
    SET @x = xbeg;    

    REPEAT INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (@x, xvalue); SET @x = @x + 1; UNTIL @x > xend END REPEAT;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur1;
END
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb97e/1) you can find my sqlfiddle;